# 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass an array  `int[]` to my function, then delete all records with a primary key in that array.

This line `.Where(t => personIds.Contains(t.PersonId)).ToList()` throws the error:

`'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments`

**This is my controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Hercules.WebApi.Models;

namespace Hercules.WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class TicketController : ApiController
    {
        private MyWebApiContext db = new MyWebApiContext();

    [Route("Ticket/removeTicketPeople")]
    public void RemoveTicketPeople([FromUri]int ticketId, [FromBody]int[] personIds)
        {
            db.TicketPeople.Where(t => t.TicketId == ticketId)
                .Where(t => personIds.Contains(t.PersonId)).ToList()
                .ForEach(t => db.TicketPeople.Remove(t));
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

  }
}
```

**This is the Person Model:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Hercules.WebApi.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        // Properties

        public String Firstname { get; set; }
        public String Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**This is the ProjectPerson link table model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Hercules.WebApi.Models
{
    public class ProjectPerson{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectPersonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Project")]
    public int? ProjectId {get;set;}
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int? PersonId {get;set;}
    public virtual Person Person {get;set;}

    public string RelationshipType {get;set;}
 }
}
```

Comment: check for a `using System.Linq;` directive. You need it.

Comment: Is `t.PersonId` really an `int`?

Comment: Try making personIds a `HashSet`.  That does have a `Contains` method.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The error message wouldn't reference `IQueryable.Contains<TSource>` if he didn't have that `using`.

Comment: Why mark the question down? I don't understand?

Comment: @HollandRisley - you're right, it doesn't deserve that. Still, provide the mising pieces (relevant usings, types etc).

Comment: Why do people keep marking this down? What can I do to improve the question?

Comment: The question still does not fit the answer. Where is the `int?` here? Something is missing or you didn't post the real actual code.

Comment: I have updated the question now to include the missing link table model definition.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is the the type of `t.PersonId` was `int?` I have now added `.Value` which changed the problem line to `.Where(t => personIds.Contains(t.PersonId.Value)).ToList()`. This now works:

```
public void RemoveTicketPeople([FromUri]int ticketId, [FromBody]int[] personIds)
        {
                db.TicketPeople.Where(t => t.TicketId == ticketId)
                .Where(t => personIds.Contains( t.PersonId.Value)).ToList()
                .ForEach(t => db.TicketPeople.Remove(t));
                db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: What is `t.PersonId`? Depending on the type, a cast will allow it to compile, but blow up at runtime.

Comment: `t.PersonId` is a primary key (int)

Comment: Apparently it's not an `int`.

Comment: Weird, you should not have needed the cast.

Comment: That's a nullable int. That makes more sense. You could call `.Value` off of it instead of casting if you know it will never be null.

Comment: `int? != int`   int? is a nullable integer, thus it can also take the value of `null` what an ordinary int can't do. There is no implicit cast from int? i to int as this causes an exception if the value is null. You should also check for null values in your WHERE clause, otherwise you will get exceptions if t.PersonID is null. And furthermore, you should reconsider if having a nullable primary key is a good idea (or remove the nullable if you are sure the value will never be null)

Comment: By the way, you can (and you should!) accept your own answer since it's how you solved your problem.